# How to construct this in regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I want to match the pattern: Starts with 0 or more spaces, followed by "ABC", then followed by anything.

So things like `"    ABC   " " ABC111111" "ABC"` would be matched. 
But things like `"   AABC" "SABC"` would not  be matched.

I tried:

```
String Pattern = "^\\s*ABC(.*)";
```

But it does not work.

Any ideas? This is in C# by the way.

Comment: Your pattern looks right to me. Are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, that pattern works for me as well - perhaps there is an error in your C# code.  Would you be able to post the code as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\\` usually puts in a literal backslash so that's probably where your solution is failing.  Unless you are doing a replace you don't need the parentheses around the `.*`

Also `\s` matches characters besides the space character `[ \t\n\f\r\x0B]` or space, tab, newline, formfeed, return, and Vertical Tab.

I would suggest:

```
String Pattern = @"^[ ]*ABC.*$";
```

Comment: C# requires you to escape the back-slashes in regexes like that.

Comment: What does adding @ in front of the pattern do?

Comment: @Saobi - A verbatim string literal consists of an @ character followed by a double-quote character, zero or more characters, and a closing double-quote character. A simple example is @"hello". In a verbatim string literal, the characters between the delimiters are interpreted verbatim, the only exception being a quote-escape-sequence. In particular, simple escape sequences and hexadecimal and Unicode escape sequences are not processed in verbatim string literals.
   From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090(VS.71).aspx

Comment: Hmm I see. And what does $ mean in your regex?

Comment: Saobi,  The $ matches until the end of the line.  It should do that anyway, but I like to be explicit. The $ does not capture any line ending characters.

Comment: @Mark, since the OP's regex is *not* in a verbatim string, the backslash in \s has to be escaped with another backslash; it is not matching a literal backslash. (BTW, you need to enclose the double-backslash in your answer in `backticks` to keep SO from swallowing one of them.)

Comment: Alan, I do not have any backslash characters in my answer.  The character class is just a space.  This is not necessary but I thought it would be clearer this way.

Comment: I meant in the text part of the answer, not the solution itself.  Here, I'll get it...

Comment: Alan,  Thanks for the edit.  I thought that had rendered correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
string pattern = @"\s*ABC(.*)"; // Using @ makes it easier to read regex.
```

I verified that this works on regexpl.com

Comment: Doesn't the ^ just force examination from the beginning of the line?

Comment: The ^ means the pattern starts at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this. It works. You can omit RegexOptions.IgnoreCase if you want only upper case ABC to be matched.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the part of the string after ABC
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">Input string</param>
/// <param name="output">Contains the string after ABC</param>
/// <returns>true if success, false otherwise</returns>
public static bool TryGetStringAfterABC(string input, out string output)
{
    output = null;

    string pattern = "^\\s*ABC(?<rest>.*)";

    if (Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);
        output = r.Match(input).Result("${rest}");
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Calling code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input = Console.ReadLine();

    while (input != "Q")
    {
        string output;
        if (MyRegEx.TryGetStringAfterABC(input, out output))
            Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("No match");
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have set the regex engine to use SingleLine and not MultiLine.